# How can I hit what I can't see?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cover

In reference, and expansion on, [This Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123791/can-a-fireball-be-cast-at-the-air-to-bypass-cover) How does one tell where that point in the air is. Meaning If I target a place above a wall, and there just so happens to be a Mountain behind it, How do I pick the point I want to hit instead of that piece of the mountain that is behind the invisible air. How would I handle this?

Comment: What is your question exactly? This seems to be more a problem one would encounter in a point-and-click game.

Comment: I'm confused by the wording here, and not sure what you mean. Firstly, you mention "how to tell where [a] point in the air is" which makes no sense to me. Second, you mention "how [to] pick the point I want to hit instead of that piece of the mountain" which is also confusing to me as the mountain was described as behind the point, so it isn't blocking your line of sight or anything. Perhaps a diagram of your situation and explaining your confusion with it might help?

Comment: If you are 500 meters away from a tall tower. The tower is in your line of sight. but you want to cast a fireball 250 meters away from you between the tall tower and yourself. Meaning you're targetting a point of air. Or empty space. Meaning how can you decide whether or not to hit that point in space instead of the tall tower.

Comment: Why do you *need* to handle this? What problem has actually arisen that requires an answer to this question? Why isn't this just something that can just be hande-waved and said to work because *we're playing an imaginary game*? Does your group really get so bogged down in that level of finicky detail?

Comment: I have a fair few players that decide rule 0 just doesnt quite cut it when they're arguing between themselves. One player argues that the spell would continue through the entire line of sight and hit the beyond tower while the other player argues that he can technically see the point in space so it should still have hit the gang of monsters.

 Yes. Yes they do.

Comment: Then maybe you should be asking about how to solve *that* problem instead (players arguing about such a (OMHO) silly thing). This seems to be an XY problem and an answer to this question isn't going to solve the underlying issue of the players arguing. Though obviously you know your group and the situation better than I do so if this is the actual issue you need to solve then feel free to ignore me.

Comment: Then it would be a duplicate question. [What should the GM do when players constantly argue?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26487/what-should-the-gm-do-when-players-constantly-argue) - [How to solve players arguing with the GM over mechanics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73844/how-to-solve-players-arguing-with-the-gm-over-mechanics)

Comment: Given that those questions appear to be what your question is _really_ about (going by extra info in the comments), **why do those questions not answer your situation?** Surely the end goal here is to get your players to stop arguing about this stuff, since proving this one point about fireballs is just firefighting the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cast fireball you pick a point. How you describe this point to your DM is up to you (“half way between me and the tower, 20m I the air”), the important thing is that you know where the point is. Your character knows where the point is too. When the fireball arrives at that point it explodes.